# pyopenssl can't set x509 certificate [cert must be an X509 instance]

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, x509certificate, pyopenssl

I'm using pyopenssl lib and I want to generate a p12 file using their crypto.PKCS12 object apis.

so this certificate value is obtained from an API and saved in a file as below:

> echo -e "-----cert text with begin & end-----" > cert.crt

which creates the file and when I run below command, there's a proper output and even when I verify it online, it shows all good:

> openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout

now the problem is when used the below to set the certificate to PKCS12 object, it gives an error:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

p12 = crypto.PKCS12()
p12.set_certificate("/home/someuser/Documents/path/to/cert.crt")
```

then it throws an error:

> File
>   "/home/someuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py",
>   line 2429, in set_certificate
>       **raise TypeError("cert must be an X509 instance")**

I can't understand why the lib is complaining about the certificate. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's required to load the certificate as an `X509` object before setting it to a `PKCS12` container.

So in the first place you should:

- Read the content of the certificate file into a buffer
- Create an X509 from the buffer using [load_certificate](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate)

As a result it may look like as follows:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

with open("/home/someuser/Documents/path/to/cert.crt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, data);

p12 = crypto.PKCS12()
p12.set_certificate(x509)
```